How to expand the argument to \defVal using globalvals package?
I would like to define a command and use its expanded content to use earlier in the document.
The globalvals package seems to do almost what I need it to do, except it stores the command verbatim in the AUX file instead of its expanded content, causing \useVal to call upon an as-of-yet non-existing command.
Consider the MWE below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{globalvals}
\begin{document}

Title

% First use the value
\useVal{myval}

% Define a command AFTER calling \useVal
\newcommand{\someval}{123}

% Attempt to save the content of that command to be used earlier
\defVal{myval}{\someval}

\end{document}

Running it results in an AUX file with the content
\relax 
\global \@namedef {useVal@myval}{\someval }
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}

but what I need (I believe) is
\relax 
\global \@namedef {useVal@myval}{123}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}

Unfortunately, my tex fu is not great and I can't manage to make it work with \protected@edef or \expandafter calls...

The globalvals package is nice, but it is not very difficult to implement the functionality yourself, with some more control over the expansion behavior. In the "Related" list at the right of this question I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520174/expand-variable-name-before-writing-to-aux-file?rq=1 which seems to do what you want.

@Marijn you're absolutely right, this fixes it. I have been completely unable to find this related question through extensive googling, I even looked at related questions that were suggested while I was making this question... but maybe I didn't look close enough. Thanks anyway!
That makes this a duplicate question

Ok, let's close it then as duplicate of Expand variable name before writing to aux file.

Note that it is not completely your fault for missing the related question: the suggestions you get while writing the question are different from the list that is shown once the question is posted. However it is a good habit to always take a quick look at that list after asking, and see if there is anything interesting there (precisely because it is different from the suggestions you get while writing).

Good one, thanks!
