# Displaying variable which is defined after the variable is used in text

Tags: cross-referencing, back-referencing, variable

I have a situation where I need to access a variable which is defined after it is used in the text. An example of what I'm trying to achieve is below, essentially the definition of variable happens later in the latex document which obviously causes a compiler error.

```
\begin{document}
\Varirable
\renewcommand{\Varirable}{Updated}
\end{document}
```

Is there anyway I can somehow forward declare the variable and when it compiles it cross-references it so it can be updated with the correct value (which is defined at the end)?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please be more specific about the value of this “variable”?

Comment: It will be text

Comment: you need to write it to the aux file so that it will be defined on the next run

Answer (score 2):

You need to write it in the `.aux` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% at point of definition, store in the aux file
\NewDocumentCommand{\definevariable}{mm}{%
  % #1 = symbolic name, #2 = value
  \iow_now:cn { @auxout } {\setvariable{#1}{#2}}
 }

% the container for the variables
\prop_new:N \g_tracey_variables_prop

% \setvariable populates the property list
\NewDocumentCommand{\setvariable}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_tracey_variables_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% \usevariable uses (or prints ??)
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevariable}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_empty:eTF { \prop_item:Nn \g_tracey_variables_prop { #1 } }
   { ?? }
   { \prop_item:Nn \g_tracey_variables_prop { #1 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\usevariable{mytext}

Some text

\definevariable{mytext}{Ööç}

\end{document}
```

First run:

[image]

Second run:

[image]

Comment: That looks ideal! 

Although i get an error saying the line with \prop_new:N \g_tracey_variables_prop, needs to be in math mode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnTracey You forgot `\ExplSyntaxOn`, I guess

Comment: I copy pasted it as above exactly including that bit.

Also i'm using overleaf incase that matters? I do also get Undefined Control Sequence for \usevariable{mytext}. Compiles fine when i comment out that line.

Comment: @JohnTracey I guess it's a spurious warning from the editor.

Comment: I think the math mode one is but the undefined control sequence one is causing the code not to run.

Comment: @JohnTracey What undefined control sequence?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416272/224969

managed to get this example to work (also from you) but when I store my counter variable it doesn't seem to be working (counter is always 0) any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnTracey You said your variable is text, not a counter's value.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't appreciate that a counter and text was different in this context

Comment: If you want the value of a counter, why not using the built-in method with `\label`and `\ref`? If you do `\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{foo}`, then `\ref{foo}` will display the value. Can you be more specific about the context where you want to use this?

Comment: Yep that sorted it! I'm very new to counters I didn't know you could do this thanks!